# columns headers of table are not visible in panel

Tags: java

the following code is working probably and the columns names are shown

```
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);

    frame.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        String str = "select * from patient ";

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(str);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but with this code the columns names are not visible

```
try {

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      String str = "select * from staff";

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(str);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception exc) {
```

can you help me please  ?

thanks

Comment: did you add table to scrollpane ?

Comment: yes i added scrollpane